# Use awk to create file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file that contain :

> Mr Q
>   01629699998
>   Ms Nhung
>   011287633
>   ...

I would like to use this `awk '{print "BEGIN:VCARD";print "Name:"$0;print "TELEPHONE:"$0;print "END:VCARD"}' file` to create this result

> BEGIN:VCARD 
>   Name: Mr Q
>   TELEPHONE:01629699998
>   END:VCARD
>   BEGIN:VCARD
>   Name: Ms Nhung
>   TELEPHONE:011287633
>   END:VCARD
>   ...

But the code above does not get that,Anyone can help me ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '{if (NR%2) printf "BEGIN:VCARD\nName: %s\n",$0; else printf "TELEPHONE:%s\nEND:VCARD\n",$0}' inputfile
BEGIN:VCARD
Name: Mr Q
TELEPHONE:01629699998
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
Name: Ms Nhung
TELEPHONE:011287633
END:VCARD
```

#### How it works

Your input file consists of pairs of lines.  The first line has a name and the second a phone number.  Thus, we want to do something different on odd numbered lines (name) and even numbered lines (phone).

- `if (NR%2)`

  This begins an `if` statement with a test based on the line number modulo 2.
- `printf "BEGIN:VCARD\nName: %s\n",$0`

  This is command executed for odd-numbered lines.
- `else printf "TELEPHONE:%s\nEND:VCARD\n",$0`

  This is what is executed for even-numbered lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure bash option using [`printf`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/printf/):

```
$ cat list_file # I have added one more entry for explanation.
Mr Q
01629699998
Ms Nhung
011287633
Dr. Drake Ramoray
0123456789

$ OLDIFS="$IFS" # save old IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'     # Set IFS to newline, because the entries are newline separated.

$ printf 'BEGIN:VCARD\nName: %s\nTELEPHONE:%s\nEND:VCARD\n' $(<list_file)
BEGIN:VCARD
Name: Mr Q
TELEPHONE:01629699998
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
Name: Ms Nhung
TELEPHONE:011287633
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
Name: Dr. Drake Ramoray
TELEPHONE:0123456789
END:VCARD

$ IFS="$OLDIFS" # restore old IFS
```

Explanation:

1. Here, printf gets 6 arguments apart from format string: 6 lines separated by newline character (which we had set as `IFS`).
2. printf then finds that its format string contains 2 `%s` entries. So, it divides 6 arguments into 3 group of 2 arguments.
3. For every group, it prints the formatted string.